# What is the type of XSynchronize in this code?

Tags: c, declaration

I am having trouble parsing this in my head and am totally confused regarding how to parse this declaration:

The typedef is something I added to confirm that this declaration does in fact compile.

```
typedef int Display;
int (*XSynchronize(Display*,int))(Display*);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSynchronize is a function that takes two arguments: (pointer to Display, int). It returns a pointer to a function that takes one argument: (pointer to Display), and returns an int.

Useful link:
http://cdecl.org/

Comment: So this? XSynchronize : (Display*,int) -> *(Display * ->  int)

Comment: Did you mean this: (Display*,int) -> *(Display * )-> int?

Answer (score 1):

A good method to parse the type of complex type declarations in C can be found in the following instruction: http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~ceng140/c_decl.pdf

[image]